# Vapor-Swift DecodingError: Could not convert MySQL data to Date

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to obtain some articles from my MySQL database using Vapor-Fluent but there is something wrong with my Date type (I have read a little bit of Date type in Vapor but I'm not sure about how to solve this issue).

This is my Vapor-Fluent model:

```swift
final class ArticleModel: Model, Content {
    
    static let schema = "tbl_article"
    
    @ID(custom: .id)
    var id: Int?
    
    @Field(key: "title")
    var title: String
    
    @Field(key: "description")
    var description: String
    
    @Field(key: "checked_out_time")
    var checkedOutTime: Date
    
    init() { }
    
    init(id: Int,
         title: String,
         description: String,
         checkedOutTime: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.checkedOutTime = checkedOutTime
    }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```swift
func getContent(req: Request) async throws -> [ArticleModel] {
    try await ArticleModel(on: req.db)
        .sort(\.$checkedOutTime)
        .all()
}
```

This is the format of my Date type in my tbl_article table (it's DATETIME type in my database):

```
2022-08-02 21:51:29
```

When I try to obtain the articles by visiting my URL, it returns the following error:

> {"error":true,"reason":"invalid field: checked_out_time type: Date error: typeMismatch(Foundation.Date, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Could not convert MySQL data to Date: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000", underlyingError: nil))"}

**My question is:**

What I have to change in order to make this work? I tried changing my model type to String but it didn't work, so maybe I have to change something related to the decoding process?

I'm new to Vapor (I'm creating my first real MySQL connection and I don't know how to solve this issue regarding the Date type).

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+MySQL+date

Comment: Can you include the output of the DESCRIBE for this field, please?

Comment: What exactly do you need @Nick? I'm a little bit lost about "DESCRIBE"... (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly sure the problem is caused by a `NULL` value in your `checked_out_time` data column.

The error definitely suggests there is a `nil` value being fetched from the database and because the data type is non-optional, it is erroring.

It should be simple to fix by defining your field as optional with `Date?`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It is returning the following error:

{"error":true,"reason":"invalid field: checked_out_time type: Optional<Date> error: typeMismatch(Swift.Optional<Foundation.Date>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: \"Could not convert MySQL data to Optional<Date>: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000\", underlyingError: nil))"}

Comment: As I can see in the database, I have 6 entries and all of them are: 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I have tried by not using those fields and the information is returned in JSON format, so my only issue here is in those Date/DATETIME decoding.

Comment: Are you able to replace those six values with NULL and try my answer? That value is the start of time for Unix timestamps, so it may be that MySQL is 'coping' with a dodgy value but swift isn't.

Comment: I tried putting that date value into one of my existing application's date fields and it worked, so it must be something specific to your database.

Comment: After changing every field to NULL in my database it displays the same error: {"error":true,"reason":"invalid field: checked_out_time type: Optional<Date> error: typeMismatch(Swift.Optional<Foundation.Date>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: \"Could not convert MySQL data to Optional<Date>: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000\", underlyingError: nil))"}

Comment: After making some changes in my database, I found that one of my fields was displaying 0000-00-00 00:00:00. After changing that to something valid like "2022-08-02 21:51:29" it started working properly.